# Is C++ Armadillo find() output sorted?

Tags: c++, find, armadillo

Does the C++ Armadillo find() function always output a sorted result, in ascending order?

Comment: Nothing in the documentation states that it is sorted, so I would not rely on that.

http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#find

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the source code, [find()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#find) processes matrices from lowest to highest linear index (0, 1, 2, ...) according to [column major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) ordering. So in that sense, the output of find() will always have increasing indices. But I wouldn't rely on this, as that's an implementation detail and nothing is mentioned in the documentation about this.